# Warning message while compiling a standalone : Extension com.livecode.interface.Control not found

Tags: livecode

I am developping a series of 6 Livecode applications. (Scientific calculations driven by graphic user interfaces). I don't want to explain the purpose of these very specialized apps, but report à warning when I save Windows and MacOS standalones for one of them.
For 5 applications, no problem, the compilation goes to the end without any error or warning message. But for the last one, after the message that the compilation was done properly, I got a warning : "1  Extension com.livecode.interface.Control not found".
I don't understand : all my 6 applications are built similarly . I use only standard Livecode functions and scripts, no external calls, stacks and card, controls available in the standard tool palette and some images paste from the clipboard. I use no special extention. But apparently something is hidden in the last app, while it is not in the 5 others. My standalone seems to work properly on MacOS and Windows. But I would like understand and fix this warning.

Any idea and help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've never seen, but I would recommend filing this as a bug with Livecode's Bugzilla system, if only because the team reads those for sure.